# simulate card swipe browser extension or a javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, credit-card

Is there a way to simulate credit card swipe in a web page? using a browser extension or a JavaScript?

I have a web page with a payment form. We test the page with swipe device and test credit cards, now not every developer has the device and we are looking for a way to somehow test this effectively in development region without the card reader device.